# In scala, why Range.hashCode() is so slow and cannot be made faster?

Tags: scala, range, hashcode

Considering the following code:

```
  def timed[T](fn: => T): (T, Long) = {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val result = fn
    val endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    (result, endTime - startTime)
  }

val t1 = timed((0 until Int.MaxValue).hashCode())
val t2 = timed((0, Int.MaxValue).hashCode())

print(t1 + " : " + t2)
```

Theoretically, the speed of hashCode() of a Range can be made to be comparable to a Tuple, instead, the difference in speed is staggering:

```
(201341306,5274) : (-281813831,0)
```

It turns out that Range inherits the hashCode() implementation of IndexSeq, which requires a full iteration. My question is, is it possible to make it faster? What is preventing it from being implemented?

Comment: IMHO, it makes sense that the `hashCode` of a **Range** would be equivalent to the one of a _collection_. Anyways, regarding o how to make it faster, you can write an extension method that computes the `hashCode` as the one of a tuple. `implicit class RangeOps(val r: Range) extends AnyVal { def tupledHashCode: Int = (r.start, r.end).hashCode }`

Answer (score 2):

In scala standard library all sequential collections are considered `equal` if they contents are equal.

```
Vector(1,2,3) == List(1,2,3) //true
```

And because of the `equals`/`hashcode` contract hashcode has to be calculated the same way for every type of collection.

Comment: I know, but there should be a shortcut for fast hashing

Comment: Optimize computation of `MurmurHash` for this particular case? Looks like a pretty hard mathematical problem.

Comment: @tribbloid Can you explain why you think there should be a fast shortcut? Remember that this has to give the same results as `Range` for any collection containing any sequence that could have been generated by a `Range`.

Comment: right now I can only hypothesise a new type of hash function that satisfy such simplification, it's definitely not MurmurHash, but I haven't figure out what it is yet :)